# I'm using JqueryUI & a Dialog box asking for a email; getting %40 instead of @

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using jQueryUI and a Dialog box to ask a user for an email address.  When I submit the form, the email shows up as emailaddy&40domain.com instead of emailaddy@domain.com.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Need your code, html and jquery, if you want some help

Comment: You need to decode the URL-encoded string. How you do so will depend on the server-side language.

Answer (score 0):

It may have more to do with form submission handling in your web app than jQuery. It looks like the query parameter wasn't unescaped after being submitted.